# why can't we do call and apply on setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, call, settimeout, apply

Why can't we do call and apply on setTimeout,

```
var obj={}
window.setTimeout.call(obj,callback,delay);//it throws error stating illegal invocation
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [WHATWG setTimeout documentation](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#dom-windowtimers-settimeout):

> The setTimeout() method must return the value returned by the timer initialisation steps, passing them the method's arguments, the object on which the method for which the algorithm is running is implemented **(a Window or WorkerGlobalScope object) as the method context**, and the repeat flag set to false.

`setTimeout` needs to be called from the context of the `window` object. The context passed into the `.call` method is not the window object. To call `setTimeout` correctly, do:

```
setTimeout.call(window, callback, delay);
```

Answer (score 3):

It makes no sense to use `.call` on `setTimeout` since `.call` is meant to invoke a function and supply context to that function when it is invoked. In other words, you're not trying to invoke ***setTimeout*** with context supplied to it, you're trying to invoke the ***callback*** with context supplied to it.

To accomplish this with `setTimeout`, you'd use .bind, as in:

```
 var obj={};
 window.setTimeout(callback.bind(obj),delay);
```