# Why can't I use call method in settimeout?

Tags: javascript, settimeout, call

The setTimeout function has a call method in --proto--. However, if you use the call method as shown below, an error occurs. Why is that?

```
myArray = ["zero", "one", "two"];
myArray.myMethod = function (sProperty) {
    alert(arguments.length > 0 ? this[sProperty] : this);
};

setTimeout.call(myArray, myArray.myMethod, 2000); // error: "NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_OP_ON_WN_PROTO: Illegal operation on WrappedNative prototype object"
setTimeout.call(myArray, myArray.myMethod, 2500, 2); // same error
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35102674/why-cant-we-do-call-and-apply-on-settimeout

Comment: Because `setTimeout` expects to be called on `window`, not on `myArray`.